# How many players have won both the senior FIFA world cup and the U-20 FIFA world cup?

Tags: football

So far I know of 5 players who won both the  senior FIFA world cup and the U-20 FIFA world cup. Messi, Di María, Maradona, Dida and Xavi. I thought perhaps there are more from Brazil or something, Brazil won the U-20 world cup in 1993 and the senior world cup in 2002.

Is the one I mentioned the full list?

How many players have won both the senior FIFA world cup and the U-20 FIFA world cup?